# MVC redirect problem

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm implementing a class for all my controllers to inherit that will redirect to login page if user is not authenticated. The RedirectToAction line is not redirecting though. Can you plesae help correct?

```
public class SecureController : Controller
    {
        public SecureController()
        {
            if (User == null || !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                RedirectToAction("Logon", "Account");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion would be to use an ActionFilter instead.  It will be much easier.  You can do something like this:

```
public class RequiresAuthenticationAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        // You can do any custom authentication logic in here

        if (User == null || !User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // This assumes that Account is the controller, and Logon is the action method.
            // You might want to check your routes if this is still not working correctly
            RedirectToAction("Logon", "Account");
        }
    }
}
```

This will let you then just put an attribute on your action method in your controller like so:

```
[RequiresAuthentication]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Or, as others have pointed out, if you do not need any custom authentication logic, you can just use the AuthorizeAttribute:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

Comment: I assumed he was needing to do custom authentication since he was going the direction he was.  This is the type of attribute I use, I just substituted out all of my custom authentication logic.

Comment: Great advice about the filter. I am implementing my own authorization logic and the filter will come in handy. Thanks.